# What is the best approach to communicate with a thermal printer within an asp.net application?

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, thermal-printer

I need to use a dll to print a barcode label on a thermal printer, within an asp.net application.

I'm considering using Silverlight 5 with PInvoke, but still do not know if this is the best strategy. The problem with this alternative is that the user will not have the dlls that I need to communicate with the printer (alternative solution: http://cureos.blogspot.com.br/2011/09/pinvoke-bundling-native-dlls-in.html).

I'm on the right track?

Suggestions?

Comment: The code need to be certified to run within the browser! This is a big limitation for me. Unfortunately, I'll have to look for alternatives such as ActiveX (blah) or similar.

Answer (score 0):

You really don't need Silverlight to leverage PInvoke.  I would use Silverlight to create a richer UI (without using 3rd party ASP.NET controls).  If you use a generic ASP.NET web application, you won't have any of the Silverlight security issues and you'll get full access to the .NET Framework without having to build a WCF service to communicate with Silverlight.

In the code behind, or leveraging an MVC design pattern, you can setup all the code you need to invoke the printer remotely and send the data from the client.  The users don't need any DLLs because the server would handle all the communication to and from the printer.